# array printing as memory location and sentinel value not working

Tags: java

I am having some issues with some homework that I cannot figure out, if someone could point me in the correct direction I would greatly appreciate it. My sentinel value is not working at all and I cannot figure it out so that it works. Also my array for my averages is printing out as memory locations and not the value. Here is the code I have so far

```
 public class DistanceFromAverage
{//Global Declaration Section

 public static void main(String args[])
 {//Declaration Section
 double[] Numbers;
 double[] Average;


 //Input Section

 Numbers = array_numbers();

 //Processing Section

Average = distance_average(Numbers);

 //Output Section

 display_array(Numbers, Average);


 }//end




  public static double[] array_numbers()
{
   double[] tmp;
   tmp = new double[20];
   double[] sentinel = {99999}; 
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int count = 0;

 try
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter number");
         tmp[i] = input.nextDouble();


      }
   }
 catch(InputMismatchException exception)
   {
      System.out.println("A number must be entered");
      System.exit(0);
   }

   return tmp; 
}//end array

public static double[] distance_average(double[] Numbers) {

     double sum = 0.0;


        for (int i=0; i < Numbers.length; i++) 

          sum = sum + Numbers[i]; 
          double average = sum / Numbers.length;


  return new double[] {average};
} // determine average



public static void display_array(double[] Numbers, double[] Average)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++){

   System.out.println("The numbers in the array are: " + Numbers[i] + "and the average is" + Average);
   }
}//end display_array







}//end class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Can you show us the output?

Comment: Two things: one, if Average holds one value only - why have it as an array? second, in the printout simply say    System.out.println("The numbers in the array are: " + Numbers[i] + "and the average is" + Average[0]); to print the lonely value in the array.

Comment: The numbers in the array are: 99.0and the average is[D@55f96302 is the first line of output. I won't list them all as there are 20 lines but they are all similar

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Average being printed as Memory Location,
Your display function accepts Average as an Array and not as a simple double.
This will call toString() on your Array class.
Since Average is just a single number, either use `Average[0]` in your 'System.out.println' statement or accept a simple average of type double in your display method like below:

`public static void display_array(double[] Numbers, double Average)`

and change the signature of

```
public static double[] distance_average(double[] Numbers) {
```

to

```
public static double distance_average(double[] Numbers) {
```